# Reduce the size of all elements in html like zooming out the page

Tags: html, css

Is it posible to reduce size off all html content inside of body tag?

I mean how to make all the content in html page to be smaller like when we zoom out the page to 90%.
For example: [from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZOVY.png) to be smaller [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEa23.png)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All HTML content inside of the body tag can be "zoomed" in and out by using the CSS zoom attribute.

For example, to zoom content to 90% simply modify the body element to

```css
body {
  zoom: 90%;
}
```

The zoom attribute can also be directly added to the body tag.

For example,

```html
<body style="zoom: 90%">
    Content Here
</body>
```

I hope this provides the help you need.

Comment: zoom helps me on chrome, edge but not works on mozzile firefox. any suggestion about that?

Comment: You could try something like transform: scale(0.5);
transform-origin: 50% 0;

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed responsive design rules then all content will shrink and grow, adjusting to the screen height and width ( Basically, when you zoom out the height and width of the window increases.)

For example, let's say in your case you've set the width of the card to be `xxpx`, then it won't be responsive it'll always be `xxpx` on all screens.
If instead, you have set the width to be `20%`, then, whatever the width of the window is you card will adjust to `20%` of the total width.

Hopefully, I have answered your question correctly.

Comment: all the content are shrink and grow (responsive) according to windows size, but I think size off all content on that html body are too big. So I want to resize all the content inside the body like it when loaded with zoom out to 90%. What is the easiest way to do that?